# Selenium claims that Displayed is true, when it is not visible (need to scroll down)

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a page with table data. There is a scroll cause all data does not fit on one page. I want to assert that last row is not visible. I have a code:

```
var element = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("last-element"));
element.Displayed // !!! true
```

I know it's probably correctly parsed, is not hidden by styles, etc, but for sure it's not visible to the **user**.

I have created:

```
static bool IsVisible(IWebElement webElement)
{
    if (webElement.Displayed == false)
    {
        return false;
    }

    RemoteWebElement remote = (RemoteWebElement) webElement;

    return remote.Location.Y == remote.LocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView.Y;
}
```

But it's behaving even stranger. After code reaches LocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView, the browser scrolls to that place.

Selenium 3.3, ChromeDriver 2.28 (the same on FirefoxDriver 0.14)

What am I missing?

Comment: I do this using Javascript method - would you be happy doing that?

Comment: @marwaha.ks please write the answer how you do it. I hoped it can be done with backend code but JS is still good.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public bool Displayed(string elementTagName, string elementAttribute, string value)
    {
            var result = false;
            try
            {
                var elementDisplayed = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript($"return $(\"{elementTagName}[{elementAttribute}=\'{value}\']:visible\").length").ToString();
                result = string.Compare("0", elementDisplayed, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //ignore exception
            }

            return result;
    }
```

returns true if the element is not displayed or false if the element is displayed.

Just pass the element variables in like so, `Displayed("div","class","rawr");`

Comment: You need to change to Equals to work:

    string.Equals("0", elementDisplayed, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == false;

Comment: It does not work as it also returns true for the selector you have there (":visible"). But it lead me that there is a problem in how I understand html not like selenium works. Thanks

Comment: @KrzysztofMorcinek could you post your solution?